# UnityHub option "Unity Editors Folder" has no effect. Hot to change where Unity Editors are installed?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

UnityHub provides posibility to install Unity Editors. Default folder of which are `C:\Program Files...`
In **Preferences** You can set different installation folder but it doesn't take any effect and Unity Editor is still installed in `C:\Program Files..`. How to setup different folder?

[image]

Comment: Hm did you try to restart the hub after changing that and try install a Unity again? For me it does exactly what you would expect... e.g. I have `E:\Unity` and get `E:\Unity\2019.3.0f1`, `E:\Unity\2019.2.14f1` etc

Comment: @derHugo so simple! Yes, it solved this problem.